# String Into Integer while sorting

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

Curious if there is a way to convert a string into an integer, only during the sort_values() process, or if it's easier to convert the variable to an integer prior to sorting and then convert back to string after sorting.

Current code ran, but code is not correct, because I believe the D_Index is actually a string, so it was sorted as 11,12,2,21,22,3 instead of 2,3,11,12,21,22. See table example and code below.

| Model | D_Index |
| --- | --- |
| First | 11 |
| Second | 12 |
| Third | 2 |
| Fourth | 21 |
| Fifth | 22 |
| Sixth | 3 |

```
df_New = df_Old.sort_values(['Model','D_Index'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a sorting key to `sort_values`:

```py
out = df.sort_values(by='D_Index', key=lambda x: x.astype(int))
```

Output:

```py
    Model D_Index
2   Third       2
5   Sixth       3
0   First      11
1  Second      12
3  Fourth      21
4   Fifth      22
```

If you want to include `Model` into it, you can use the Series' name:

```py
df.sort_values(by=['Model','D_Index'], key=lambda x: x.astype(int) if x.name=='D_Index' else x)
```

Output (in your example, the sorting is trivial, since no `Model` has different `D_Index`es):

```py
    Model  D_Index
4   Fifth       22
0   First       11
3  Fourth       21
1  Second       12
5   Sixth        3
2   Third        2
```

Comment: How would I apply this, with 'Model' variable included in the sort function?

Comment: Sort 'Model' alphabetically and 'D_Index' numerically.

Comment: Thank you @enke ! Will do more homework on how to apply lambda in other areas

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function:

```
df.sort_values(by='D_Index', key=lambda col: col.astype(float))
```

Comment: How would I apply this, with 'Model' variable included in the sort function?

Comment: By which column do you actually want to sort?

Comment: Sort 'Model' alphabetically and 'D_Index' numerically.

Comment: You can simply sort two times, but the sorting of D_Index is irrelevant in this exact case.